# Hom($P$, $R$) $\neq 0 $ if $P$ is a nonzero projective left $R$-module (Rotman)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

I've found this exercise, number $3.11$ from Introduction to homological algebra.

Prove that $\operatorname{Hom}(P, R) \neq 0 $ if $P$ is a nonzero projective left $R$-module.

Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $P\oplus P'=R^{(\Lambda)}$ (a free module) for some set $\Lambda$ and some module $P'$.